# How do I format the output of COUNT in SPARQL to be only a number?

Tags: rdf, sparql

```
SELECT ?class (count(distinct ?subClass) AS ?noci)  
WHERE { ?class jooo:hasJSubClass ?subClass}  
GROUP BY?class
```

I have the right answer but in the following format: `"2"^^<http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>`. I need the answer to be only 2, So what can i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the lexical form — the `"2"` in `"2"^^xsd:integer` — use `str()`:

```
SELECT ?class (str(count(distinct ?subClass)) AS ?noci)
```

but note when talking about `"2"^^xsd:integer`, that is due to the surface appearance only — in Turtle, it can be `2` (with no `""`).  It's just syntax.

All literals (in RDF 1.1) have a lexical part and a datatype URI (and some have a lang tag in which case the datatype is `rdf:langString`). In RDF-2004 (AKA RDF 1.0), there are plain literals and datatype literals.